# phpmyadmin shows directory only when installed on iis Server

Tags: phpmyadmin, windows-server

I'm installing Phpmyadmin in windows 10 IIS server. the problem I'm facing is after creating a new website as phpmyadmin  and gave the path of my downloaded MySQL folder
Php 8 enabled
CGI module Enabled
now when I type the URL I'm getting the list of directories.
than I tried to use index.php in URL but than the complete page shows white blank color.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to install PHP

- Download ZIP file : https://windows.php.net/download/

- The VC15 and VS16 builds require to have the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015-2019 x64 or x86 installed